# UI gets hang when response stream doesn't get disposed

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, wcf, service

I have one WPF application in MVVM. From my view model I am making an HTTP call to get data from server. I get the data from my service, but my UI hangs.

When I flush the response stream then it works fine. I used  stream object in `using` and it works:

```
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())                  
{
}
```

Can anyone explain why the WPF UI hangs when I do not flush the streamed object?
I used a background worker to make the server call.